# How to display the current time and date in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

How do you display the current date and time in a label in c#

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You'd need to set the label's text property to `DateTime.Now`:

```
labelName.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

You can format it in a variety of ways by handing `ToString()` a format string in the form of `"MM/DD/YYYY"` and the like. (Google Date-format strings).

Comment: I agree, but I think we should be pusing standards based dates (YYYY-MM-DD, or even better: YYYY.MM.DD)

Comment: @Kendrick my point wasn't what based-date we should use, just that you can format it.  As far as standards based dates: no customer is going to be happy with that.  Those of us with customers *can't* use "Standards" based dates.

Comment: I understand customer requirements, but if you're worried about that you should use locale information to format your dates, not a format string.  If you only ever plan to have U.S. based customers, I guess you can get away with this, but if you go global you'll have a lot more pissed off customers with MM/DD/YYYY than with YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: @kendrick string Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Answer (score 17):

For time:

```
label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); //result 22:11:45
```

or

```
label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt"); //result 11:11:45 PM
```

For date:

```
label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(); //30.5.2012
```

Answer (score 16):

The [`System.DateTime` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) has a property called [`Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx), which:

> Gets a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) object that is set to the current date and time on this computer, expressed as the local time.

You can set the [`Text` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.text%28VS.90%29.aspx) of your label to the current time like this (where `myLabel` is the name of your label):

```
myLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Answer (score 9):

```
labelName.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd , MMM dd yyyy,hh:mm:ss");
```

Output:

[image: ][1]

Answer (score 4):

**If you want to do it in XAML,**

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}}"
```

**With some formatting,**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now},
                  StringFormat='{}{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss}'}"
```

Answer (score 2):

> DateTime.Now.Tostring();

. You can supply parameters to To string function in a lot of ways like given in this link
http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

This will be a lot useful. If you reside somewhere else than the regular format (MM/dd/yyyy)

**use always MM not mm, mm gives minutes and MM gives month.**

Answer (score 0):

In WPF you'll need to use the Content property instead:

```
label1.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

```csharp
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (true)
  {
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Start();
    label3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd , MMM dd yyyy,hh:mm:ss");
  }
}
```

update time every second

Comment: The `if(true)` is completely unnecessary. The implementation of the timer is incomplete and won't do anything.

Answer (score -2):

```
label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();//its for current date

label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();//its for current time
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer and update it so it’s not just a code only answer

Comment: its just for display the current time and date in C#