# How to show date and time in one label?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How to show date and time in one label?

```
lbldatetime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

I want it in 05-10-2013 9:47am format.

Comment: Check this link for date and time formats http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display the current time and date in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380639/how-to-display-the-current-time-and-date-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "tt" for the AM/PM designator:

```
lbldatetime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy h:mmtt");
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for the complete reference.

Comment: `MM:dd:yyyy h:mmtt` will display `05:10:2013 9:47am`

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date and time with the `ToString()` Method:

```
lbldatetime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy h:mmtt");
```

Comment: I used txtdatetime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(); and its working fine thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using format provider to convert date time value in particular format

for more learn about format please review this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Thank you.